# launching a visio diagram in Sharepoint so that links to other visio diagrams open in the same tab overwrite fprevious diagram

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, visio

I have created a document library in Sharepoint of visio business process flow maps with relationships/hyperlinks to other visio diagrams in the library.
when I click on the activity box to launch a associated diagram, it opens in a new tab.

I want it to overwrite the document, in the same tab, how can that be done?